# Comparing proportions of 3 groups using chi square and z-test

Tags: chi-squared-test, post-hoc, z-test

I was wondering if my plan for analyzing my data was appropriate:
I am trying to compare proportions between samples from 3 populations (N= 53, 54, and 56). I ran a chi squared test and found a significant difference. Now I would like to determine which groups differ. My plan is to run z-tests between each pair of groups, and then perform bonferroni corrections on the resulting p-values. Does this seem correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If you ran a chi-square test for the omnibus test, why not run chi-square tests for the post-hoc tests?

Comment: @Sal It should be the same, as long as both types of test deal with the continuous approximation of a discrete distribution in a consistent manner.

Comment: You're right I'm going to use chi-square as post-hoc as well thanks

Comment: Another post-hoc approach is to look at the standardized residuals from the analysis.  If the value is > 1.96 or < –1.96, then the cell is... interesting... at the 0.05 level.  It also might make sense to present proportions with multinomial confidence intervals.